# Simple ruby array splitting

Tags: ruby

I would like to split my array in the following way:

```
current_arr = [1,2,3,4,5]

new_arr = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5]]
```

`#each_slice` and `#combination` are close to what I want but not quite.
How could I split my array as in the example?

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer. You don't want to see others?

Comment: The question is not clear. There are different logics (which would lead to different results given if parameters were changed) to create the output you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[1,2,3,4,5].each_cons(3).to_a
#=> [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]
```

Check doc for [each_cons](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons).

Comment: @tadman: true that. I'm doing some Go now and I miss the Enumerable :)

Comment: I want to port Enumerable to *everything* for that reason.

Comment: @tadman, Enumerable would be a nothing-burger without Enumerator. It's the latter that's most deserving of our praise. Yes?

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun:

```
ary = [1,2,3,4,5]

n = 3
(ary.size - n + 1).times.each_with_object([]) { |_, a|  a << ary.first(n); ary.rotate! }

#=> [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]
```